# In Chrome, how do I see a suspect HTTPS certificate before I visit the site?

Tags: certificates, chrome

If I attempt to connect to an HTTPS site with a certificate problem, Google Chrome displays the following:

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information...

It then offers `ADVANCED` and `Back to safety` options. Clicking on `ADVANCED` allows me to:

> Proceed to highly.suspicious.server.com (unsafe)

Question: How do I examine the server's certificate *before* I visit the website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you view the certificate:

1. Click the lock sign (it should have a red "x") in the address bar.

**EDIT to Roger's request**: This icon (which could also be a triangle on other versions of Chrome) is **clickable on the warning page itself**

2. Click the "Details" link after this text:"Your connection to this site is not private"

[image]

3. Click the "View Certificate" button in the new Developer Tools window that opens up.

[image]